# Difference between a lock in amplifier and an oscilloscope

Tags: amplifier, oscilloscope, snr

I'm a physics student and in my lab we are currently dealing with lock-in amplifiers.

So far the thing that I found out is that an oscilloscope displays a signal in the time domain and a lock-in amplifier displays it in the frequency domain (as the sum of many sine waves with differing amplitudes, frequencies and phases.)

I didn't have too much luck finding any more explanations than this so I've wanted to try and ask here if anyone could give me some insights in this and in which use-cases you would chooses either the one or the other.

One guess from me would be that I use the lock-in amplifier when I want to extract a small signal from a rleative broad noise. (That's my only guess because that is what we use the lock-in in our laboratory for.)

Comment: An oscilloscope is an ensemble of a lot of functions, filtering among them, while a lock-in amplifier is just a filter, more or less. An oscilloscope may (and does) include one or more filters, a filter cannot even include one oscilloscope.

Comment: I've never come across a lock-in amplifier but I see Wikipedia has an article on the subject and will certainly have one on the oscilloscope. Did you check there?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the difference between an oscilloscope and a spectrum analyzer, not a lock-in amplifier.

Comment: Markus, See section 8.14ff of the 3nd edition of "The Art of Electronics." Lock-in detection and lock-in amplifiers are reasonably well discussed there. (They also discuss commercially available units elsewhere in the text.)